# Howto: linux graphical login with restrictions (sort of like a hotel lobby screen)

Tags: linux, desktop, desktop-customization

I have seen such screens at hotels. But on windows systems. You startup, login and get a restricted screen. Things like getting a shell are not possible. A menu with only internet surfing and office programs for example are possible to start.

How can this be done on linux and which distribution would be best suited for such a setup.
So at login there should be:
- a menu with only the programs of your choice (eg. writer, calc and firefox)
- Further only logout and shutdown
- No way to get to a shell and do funny things

Currently I use ubuntu 18.04LTS but I can imagine that different distribution and/or desktop environment is needed to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You startup, login and get a restricted screen.

It's called Kiosk Mode.

There is a tutorial here [Make a secure Ubuntu kiosk | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#1-overview).

It's too long to include the whole thing in an answer, but here are some highlights.

> **Overview**
>
> A kiosk or smart display is a full-screen application running on a
>   secure device, with the sole purpose of driving that display to
>   provide specific information or a particular function at that
>   location.
>
> Ubuntu is popular for these applications thanks to its excellent
>   security track record and widespread developer familiarity. We
>   compiled this guide to a reference kiosk architecture to enable
>   anybody, anywhere to make a highly secure kiosk using any of the
>   popular application display frameworks - HTML5/web, X11, or native
>   Wayland.
>
> Since these devices are often left unattended for long periods of
>   time, and run in sensitive environments like airports, hospitals and
>   public areas we also want to raise the bar on security and update
>   management. So this tutorial includes the option to use Ubuntu Core,
>   which is a minimal, self-updating OS for your application to run on.

And:

> **What you’ll need**
>
> - An Ubuntu desktop running any current release of Ubuntu or an Ubuntu Virtual Machine on another OS.
> - A ‘Target Device’ from one of the following:
>
>   - A device running Ubuntu Core 18.
>       [This guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/installation-medias) shows you how to set up a supported device. If there’s no supported image that fits your needs you can create your
>       own core image.
>   - Using a Virtual Machine (VM) You don’t need to have a physical “Target Device”, you can follow the tutorial with Ubuntu Core
>       in a VM. Install the ubuntu-core-vm snap: sudo snap install --beta
>       ubuntu-core-vm --devmode For the first run, create a VM running the
>       latest Core image: sudo ubuntu-core-vm init From then on, you can spin
>       it up with: sudo ubuntu-core-vm You should see a new window with
>       Ubuntu Core running inside. Setting up Ubuntu Core on this VM is the
>       same as for any other device or VM. See, for example,
>       https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/kvm.
>   - Using Ubuntu Classic You don’t have to use Ubuntu Core, you can use also a “Target Device” with Ubuntu Classic. Read [this
>       guide](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/howto-run-your-kiosk-snap-on-your-desktop/11180) to understand how to run kiosk snaps on your desktop, as the
>       particular details won’t be repeated here.